# Force controller action not to return an HTTP status code (or render invalid response)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that Rails will attempt to render a 200 status code, along with a template matching the controller and action, if I don't call `render` explicitly in the action.

Is there a way to prevent Rails from doing this, and return no HTTP status code at all? Or, could I have the controller render an invalid response? The short reason is that I am trying to make use of a delegate method in Objective C that fires only when an HTTP request does not receive a valid response.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or, could I have the controller render an invalid response?

Sure, if you don't want to send any body with your response you could just write in your controller:

```
head :bad_request
```

If you want to render and still sends and invalid response code:

```
 render status: 500
 render status: :forbidden
```

Everything can be found in the documentation here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-status-option